# How to get SQL result of query to map to nested model

Tags: c#, sql, .net, api, model

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT d.domain_id, d.name, sd.subdomain_id, sd.name, sd.[description] 
FROM [myDB].SubDomains sd INNER JOIN [myDB].Domains d 
ON d.domain_id = sd.domain_id ORDER BY d.[name], sd.[name]
```

This returns following result:

```
domain_id | name | subdomain_id |name | description
1             A       11          AB      AB description
1             A       12          AC      AC description
2             B       21          BA      BA description
```

I have C# Model as follows:

```
// This is Domain Mapping as we can have list of domains
public class HigherLevel
{
  public List<DomainModel> Domains { get; set; }
}
public class DomainModel
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<SubDomainModel> SubDomains { get; set; }
}
public class SubDomainModel
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to keep the model same as in API I need response as:

```
 HigherLevel: {
      domains: [{
                    id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  }]
                },
                {   id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  },
                                 { id: ,name: , description:  }]
                },
                    id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  }]
                },
                {   id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  },
                                 { id: ,name: , description:  }]
                }]
}
```

On Higher Level, there can be multiple domains and inside which there can be multiple subdomains.
I would like to know how can I return the SQL result to map to model so that it can put result into a nested list of domains-> subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your object model, the (json) structure you'd want would be:

```
HigherLevel: {
      domains: [{
                    id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  }]
                },
                {   id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  },
                                 { id: ,name: , description:  }]
                },
                    id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  }]
                },
                {   id:, 
                    name:,
                    subdomains: [{ id: ,name: , description:  },
                                 { id: ,name: , description:  }]
                }]
}
```

Next, the Linq to get the same result set would be:

```
var data = (from d in db.Domains
            join sd in db.SubDomains on d.DomainId equals sd.DomainId
            orderby d.Name, sd.Name
            select new 
            { 
               Id = d.DomainId, 
               Name=d.name,
               SubdomainID =  sd.SubdomainId, 
               SubDomainName = sd.Name,
               Description = sd.Description
            }).ToList();
```

Now, I can't see a simple way to move that data into the structure you want, so let's do it in a loop.

```
   var domainId = -1;
   var higherLevels = new HigherLevel();
   higherLevels.Domains = new List<Domain>(); // should be handled in ctor
   Domain domain = null;
   foreach(var row in data)
   {
       if (row.DomainId != domainId)
       {
            domainId = row.DomainId;
            domain = new Domain();
            domain.SubDomains = new List<SubDomain>(); // again, in ctor
            domain.Id = row.Id;
            domain.Name = row.Name;
            higherLevels.Domains.Add(domain);
        }
        var sd = new SubDomain();
        sd.Id = row.SubDomainId;
        sd.Name = row.SubDomainName;
        sd.Description = row.Description;
        domain.SubDomains.Add(sd);

    }
   return higherLevels;
```

Comment: I can not use ORM to access SQL table classes so I can not use Linq. Is there other way to map the records as list. The main issue is mapping multiple sub domains to one domain. I can create a domain list and when fetching first record, it can add subdomains to main domain list and in second iteration I can check if the list is not empty or has at least one record if so I can add next subdomain to same domain list.